# Есть ли в Oracle БД наследование таблиц?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, oracle, наследование

Есть ли в Oracle БД наследование таблиц аналогично [`INHERITS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-inheritance.html) в PostgreSQL?

Если нет, то какими способами можно достигнуть такой функциональности?

Comment: Можно достичь с помощью связи один к одному

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть, с ключевым словом `UNDER`. Подробности в офф. док. [Inheritance in SQL Object Types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/inheritance-in-sql-object-types.html#GUID-D6D92FB6-7BC4-4EE6-A9EC-BC69C5BA5A56).
Работает так:

```sql
create or replace type itemBase as object (
    id number, name varchar2 (16)) not final not instantiable;
/
create or replace type item under itemBase (memo varchar2 (255)) final;
/
create table items of item;

insert into items values (item (1, 'myname', 'my memo'));

select * from items;
```

Последний запрос выведет:

```
ID NAME             MEMO    
-- ---------------- --------
 1 myname           my memo
```

Comment: Спасибо. Для себя решил, что лучше воспользоваться объектным представлением.

Comment: Рад был помочь! Почему лучше? Это же одно и тоже.

Comment: Да я решил не опираться на эти объекты прям сильно, мне просто достаточно было оказывается 1 уровня глубины.

Comment: Ну что я могу тут посоветовать? Мало инпута для вашей задачи в целом. Я всего лишь ответил на конкретный вопрос. Если будут какие сложности, обращайтесь.